# Interface not registered (0x80040155) on return from COM call

Tags: c++, com

I'm making a synchronous cross-process COM call that executes successfully, but when I check the HRESULT returned it's the aforementioned 0x80040155, or "Interface not Registered" and the out parameter doesn't contain any data.

Is there a way to re-register COM executibles?  I'm not even sure that this would fix it, so is there an alternative way to fix this?

This problem appears to be localized to a particular system, as it works successfully on other systems.

Comment: If it executed *successfully*, it probably wouldn't return an *error* code starting with 0x8...

Comment: Can you describe your setup a little? Who developped the component? Is it in house? How did you register it on other machines?

Comment: Both are in-house components, but I'm not sure how the callee process gets registered. I'm following that up separately.  When I say it executed "successfully", I mean that I can see the logging in the function getting called occurring and no errors are logged out.  But yes, you are correct on that point.

Comment: This looks like a proxy/stub is not registered. Have you checked that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most COM executables can be registered by running `COMserver.exe /regserver`

Answer (score 1):

After registering the COM executables, I still received the same `Interface not Registered` error.

I was able to get rid of the exception by repairing Visual Studio.  You can do by clicking *Repair* in the setup wizard, or in Visual Studio 2017, open the **Visual Studio Installer** then click *Additional Choices* -> *Repair*.